# Batch file isn't finding the files to work on

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file

I have a Windows batch file:

```
   @echo on
    set bindirectory=K:\Physics\bin\1112
    set coredirectory=K:\Physics\cores
    set quiet=yes

for %%f in ( %coredirectory% ) do (

    call %bindirectory%\RunMSFlux.bat %%f measbu measbu
)
```

Basically I'm trying to process a large number of files in the core directory, with a program that resides in the bin directory (RunMSFlux.bat).  But when I run the program I get an error:

> K:\Physics\bin\1112\RunMSFlux.bat Stop.  Core File not found: K:\Physics\cores

Even though I specified the directory in the batch file with the coredirectory variable, and I'm using the %%f to denote the file name.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Looks fine... The file exists?

Comment: Yeah, the directory is full of files.  I wonder if the problem is with RunMSFlux.bat.  It can't handle variables like %%f, it needs to be given an actual filename.

Comment: Preceede the line Change the line `call %bindirectory%\RunMSFlux.bat %%f measbu measbu` with echo and you'll see your problem.

Comment: you don't look for any files. Therefore no files are returned. Try `... in (%coredirectory%\*) do ...`

Comment: It still doesn't work, although it seems to be passing the name of the core file to RunMSFlux: 

`code`----------------------------------------------- K:\Physics\bin\1112\RunMSFlux.bat Stop. `code`Core File not found: K:\Physics\cores\c_000218~a ----------------------------------------------- 

`code`K:\Physics\cores>(K:\Physics\bin\1112\RunMSFlux.bat K:\Physics\cores\c_000219~a measbu measbu )

Comment: `K:\Physics\cores\c_000218~a` is the exact name of one of the files? (it looks strange to me)

Comment: I think the issue is that RunMSFlux is looking for a filename like 000218~a, not c_000218~a.  It can't process the actual filename and instead expects a number as the start of the filename.  Is there a way to modify the batch file so that it cuts off the 'c_' and just hands RunMSFlux.bat the 000218~a?